# how to use VscrollBar to be able to change the background color of the panel in c# using Color.FromArgb() method?

Tags: c#

here is the code :

```
 private void vScrollBar1_Scroll(object sender, ScrollEventArgs e)
        {
            //chage the color of the panel1 using Color.FromArgb() method

        }
```

if you know how to i wish that you'll tell..
Thank You before you do

Comment: Your question is not clear and does not convey what you want to achieve. There are mysterious controls (panel1 ?) and missing values (what will be passed to FromArgb() ?). Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). If what you want is to change the back color of the panel using the current value of the scroll bar, please say so, but still, is it gray scale? You need at least three values to get a color other than one of the tones of gray

Comment: yes sir i want to change the back color of the panel using the current value of the scroll bar

Comment: Please add more details, and please add them to your question. What is the value range of your vscroll? What values will be feeded into FromArgb()? vscroll will provide one value, is there a map of colors using this value? It is impossible to get an answer with so few details.